# SSRS 2008 referenced assembly returning incorrect value

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS Report that references an assembly. I call a method on the referenced assembly that is supposed to provide me a value. When I reference this assembly from a console application and call the method, the correct value is returned. When I reference this same assembly in SSRS and call the method with the same parameters I use in the console application, the incorrect value gets returned. This makes no sense. Why does it behave one way in one environment and another (incorrect) way in SSRS?

I have tried removing and re-referencing the assembly, deleting the .rdl.data file, putting the assembly and (any dependent assemblies) in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure the assembly is .net 3.5 I haven't seen incorrect values, but I have seen type mistmatches when using a .net 4.0 custom data provider with SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this value one that might be affected by 32-bit vs 64-bit calculations? That may be the source of your discrepancy.

Comment: Not quite the problem I had, but your post got me thinking in a different mindset, which led to me eventually finding the issue. Turns out it was security related.

Comment: you should probably post exactly what your solution was, so the next person that comes across as similar problem might find it.